# How to release picture from picturebox so picture file may be deleted in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, file-io, picturebox

I have a picture box `ThePic` on the form `PicViewer` that is assigned an image using the below code from an array of possible picture names (`FileNameSt`) stored in `PicList` where CurNum is the array position of the file name:

```
Private Sub LoadPic(ByVal FileNameSt As String)
    Me.ThePic.Load(PixFolderPath & "/" & FileNameSt)
End Sub
```

Once the user has loaded the picture into the form, they have the option to delete the picture from the file. The code I am trying to do this with is as follows:

```
 Private Sub DelButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DelButton.Click

    Dim Resetter As Boolean
    Resetter = False

    If Not PixLoaded Then Exit Sub 'User has not selected a file to load pics from
    If UBound(PicList) = LBound(PicList) Then PixLoaded = False 'Last pic was deleted
    Me.ThePic.Image = Nothing
    Me.ThePic.Invalidate()
    Me.ThePic.Refresh()
    If Not PixLoaded Then
        Me.ThePic.Image = My.Resources.NoMorePics 'Out of pics picture
        Me.ThePic.Refresh()
        GoTo Finisher
    End If

    'Go to the next image available
    If CurNum = UBound(PicList) Then
        LoadPic(PicList(LBound(PicList)))
        Resetter = True
    Else
        LoadPic(PicList(CurNum + 1))
    End If

 Finisher:
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(PixFolder & "/" & PicList(CurNum))

    If Not PixLoaded Then Exit Sub 'Exits if on last pic

    LoadPictures(PixFolder) 'Resets PicList array values 
    If Resetter Then CurNum = LBound(PicList)
End Sub
```

My issue comes when the user is trying to delete the last picture out of the file. For some reason I get the "The process cannot access the file 'File Name Here' because it is being used by another process." error on `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(PixFolder & "/" & PicList(CurNum))`. How do I remove the picture file from being used by my form so it can actually be deleted?

Comment: You must call Me.ThePic.Image.Dispose() before you set it to Nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant I added the line `Me.ThePic.Image.Dispose()` before the `Me.ThePic.Image = Nothing` line and I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: You are missing some more Dispose() calls.  That LoadPictures() method call certainly looks like a trouble-maker.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think there is an issue with the `LoadPictures()` call  since all it is doing is re-loading the array `Pic List` with the names of the remaining files in the folder and not actually displaying an image. Also, I can delete hundreds of pix out of a folder with the code as it is, it just hangs up on the last one (I've checked the name in the error message against what's in the folder), so I think the `picturebox.load` method is releasing the previous image. The last one loaded from resources is using a different method that does not release the previous image.

Comment: The Load() method does *not* release anything.  If you are calling Load() without having called Dispose() on the existing Image then you'll have the exact same problem.

Comment: Interesting, and good to know! Also, I switched `Me.ThePic.Load(PixFolderPath & "/" & FileNameSt)` to `Me.ThePic.Image = Image.FromFile(PixFolder & "/" & FileNameSt)` in the `LoadPic()` sub and that seemed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `FileStream` instead of `.Load`

```
Dim strImageFileName As String
strImageFileName = PixFolderPath & "/" & FileNameSt
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
fs = New System.IO.FileStream(strImageFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
ThePic.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Close()
```

So you will not need to release it.